# Problem in inserting text in text widget of python

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox, attributeerror

```
from tkinter import *

class btr(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(btr, self).__init__()
        self.ticket = Text(self,height=12, width =70, bd = '10').grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.ticket.insert(INSERT, "abcdefg")
        self.ticket.insert(END, "abcdefg")

    btr().mainloop()
```

Please help me. I am very new to tkinter(Python).
I was making a GUI Program but I getting this error
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'`
please help me as fast as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying set `.grid()` for `Text`, not for its instance.

Simply set `.grid()` after created an instance of `Text`:

```
class Btr(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Btr, self).__init__()
        self.ticket = Text(self, height=12, width=70, bd='10')
        self.ticket.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.ticket.insert(INSERT, "abcdefccg")
        self.ticket.insert(END, "abcdefgx")


Btr().mainloop()
```

Comment: I am very glad for your answer>

Comment: thank you most for this

Comment: Thank you for your words. Please, also rate up the answer or/and select it as correct :)